# "Error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line" when using -nodefaultlibs

Tags: c, gcc, arguments, x11

I'm trying to reduce the file size of the (with `gcc` on Linux) compiled binary trough using `-nodefaultlibs`.

This is how the command looks `gcc -nodefaultlibs src/main.c -o test -lX11`.

It may be because it links to x11, but I'm not sure.

Comment: "I'm trying to reduce the file size" Why? Most standard libs (e.g.) `libc` are _shared_ libraries so your program will _link_ to them, but code/data from them are _not_ embedded in your app, so they don't take up additional space. For _some_ programs, the compiler generates calls to `libgcc.a` that _must_ be resolved (e.g.) for XMM/AVX floating point operations. IMO, don't worry--be happy.

Comment: There's a really cool video about fitting a game into a QR-Code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExwqNreocpg&t=319s, which I am trying to replicate. So in this case the binary has to be under 3kb and it sadly does matter.

Comment: Something is amiss. The video says that a "simple hello world" program took 100KB?!?! I built it here [under linux and _not_ windows] and it took 1150 bytes. So, hmm ... I'm quite familiar with small memory programs and I'm cringing when watching the video -- YMMV

Comment: I can only assume that that's Visual Studio on Windows at work there with it's compiler. I tried compiling a c file with just a main function now, and I get 17,1kb. Just using `gcc test.c`, so something seems out of the ordinary.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You cannot simply reduce the file size using `-nodefaultlibs`, but you have to replace the library functions (such as `malloc()`) by self-written functions if you use that switch. I already used the `-nodefaultlibs` switch to reduce the file size in the following situation: On the target System (Windows), the `libc` library was not available as DLL so it had to be linked statically. Instead, I wrote some wrapper functions (e.g. `malloc()`) that called equivalent functions (e.g. "LocalAlloc()") from another DLL that was available. ...

Comment: ... If your executable file is linked dynamically (all libraries are included as `.DLL` or `.so` files) right now, it is very **improbable** that it is possible to lower the size of the executable file unless it is something very simple like a "hello world".